# How to debug speechSynthesis that isn't making any sound

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis

I am using the SpeechSynthesis API in its simplest form, basically

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
msg.text = 'Saying something'
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg)
```

Even if I run this in the console I hear no sound. How do I debug something like this? I know the code is working but I get no audio output from any browser I try.

Comment: you not selected a voice

Comment: Start with the obvious: does YouTube produce sound or is there a problem with your computer? If that's OK try the events e.g. msg.onerror = (err) => console.log(err); Also try running speechSynthesis.cancel();

Comment: @Frazer, computer's audio is working fine, tried the onerror log with no results, also tried speechSynthesis.cancel earlier and again now and didn't fix it. Everything is lined up properly and seems like it will run except no sound comes out and I can't figure out why

Comment: @Antoine Another back to basics: try clearing the browser cache. Otherwise add msg.onstart = (e) => console.log(e); and msg.onend = (e) => console.log(e); then run the speak command again and see if it logs anything odd.

Comment: Also try resetting msg.pitch to its default of 1, as the default voice doesn't work except on multiples of 0.5 (assuming you're using Windows).

Comment: What OS do you use? Does `getVoices()` return anything (you can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/getVoices#HTML))?

Comment: On iOS/Safari, watch out for the soft mute button.  Executing this from the javascript console should work, but this code won't work from most browsers unless it is initiated by a user click.